# Is it valid to evaluate a flan-t5 model on sequences longer than it's max_length of 2048 tokens (assuming I have enough memory)?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I am evaluating the different flan-t5 models with few-shot chain of thought prompts which can go over the 2048 maximum token length. I am under the impression that because T5 uses relative position encoding, that it would be valid (make sense) to do zero shot on sequences longer than 2048, provided that I can handle the quadratic memory scaling, but wanted to double check if that is indeed the case.

Way I see it, the linear mappings only learn relative dependencies from the relative positional encodings, so evaluation should still be valid on longer sequences even if it was not actually trained on sequences of that length. The only issue I think of would be of that it would not learn a pattern for relative dependencies longer than 2048.

Comment: The [long-t5 model](https://huggingface.co/models?search=longt5), which is specifically created to handle long inputs, might be relevant to you.